# how to create download and install link for ipa file?

Tags: php, ios, ipa

How can I put my `ipa` file on my personal server as a php link to other users, by clicking the download link and installing the program on Safari?
I want to create download `ipa` link in php code.

Comment: What have you tried? Any atempts made?

Comment: @DieterKräutl  i put my ipa file in my mysql. i want to make a link to a php file by clicking on it to download and install my application.

Comment: Can you show us the table? Is the problem that you don't know php or sql, or is it that you tried something but didn't work?

Comment: Are you trying to allow people with Jailbreak phones to install your app? Or is this for AdHoc testing? Otherwise, you cannot do that to begin with.. apps can only be distributed through the App Store.

Comment: @DonMag no, i’d like to install other non- jailbreak devices. but outside of apple stores. for the enterprise users i’m working on.

Comment: You need to install manifest, which Xcode can create. This is just a plist file. Also you need to host your files on HTTPS with a valid SLL certificate.

Comment: @JavadMahmoodi - ok, that's not really a question for Stack Overflow (it's not code related). Searching for `iOS Enterprise Distribution` finds many resources. Quick look, and this looks like a decent article: https://www.goodbarber.com/blog/distribute-your-ios-app-out-of-the-store-with-the-apple-developer-enterprise-program-a871/

Comment: @DonMag tanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the header to your wanted document type and then you need to print the file/mysql entry you want to make available to download.